# Understanding Javascript variable scope

Tags: javascript

```
foo: function () {
  var bValue = false;

  boo(2, function () {
    bValue = true;
    if (bValue)
      alert("bvalue is true 1");
  });

  if (bValue)
    alert("bvalue is true 2");
}

boo: function (val, fn) {
  fn();
}
```

I am doing something similare in my code and not able to get second alert. Do you see any issues in code above.

Comment: Is boo a separate function from foo?  Shouldn't it need its own declaration?  Where is it?

Comment: where is `boo` defined?

Comment: How can you call `boo()` directly like that from within `foo`? `boo` looks like it is a property of the enclosing object.

Comment: Please post *valid* code - this is likely the reason for all the down-votes.

Comment: My intention is to understand scope of bValue variable, if I am using it correctly.I am using similar code like above but not above code.This code I mentioned to figure out problem in my actual code.

Comment: Anyway, scoping is easy: a new variable scope is created for every *new* function context. However, without a `var` (in the given function context) the the variable will be resolved in the parent context scope and so forth ..

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing label on function statement. Instead of

```
boo: function (val, fn) {
  fn();
}
```

you should write

```
function boo(val, fn) {
  fn();
}
```

The same problem is with `foo`. This will cause a `SyntaxError` and stop the whole script from executing. Fortunately, it's easy to catch if you look into the console.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the second alert does not execute.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Will the first one execute? No, I don't believe so. If there were no errors, both alerts should be executed.

Comment: The OP's question is not very clear. I'm assuming that there is an enclosing object and it is only the second alert that isn't executing (since he didn't mention anything about the first alert). If what he has above is how he is defining his functions, then your answer is correct and he has to brush up on JS syntax.